# How to produce this output processing strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having trouble producing this output:

```
   *     +   **** ****
  ***    +   ***   ***
 *****   +   **     **
*******  +   *       *
 *****   +   **     **
  ***    +   ***   *** 
   *     +   **** ****
```

I've made something which produces only a quarter of the desired output:

```
asterisks = 7
for i in range(asterisks // 2+1): 
    print(((1+i*2)*'*').center(asterisks))
```

Which makes this:

```
   *   
  ***  
 ***** 
*******
```

Comment: That's a good start. What's giving you trouble with other parts? Do you know how to concatenate strings?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow! Note that Stack Overflow is a place to get specific answers to your programming questions, not a code-writing service. Please make an effort to solve the problem yourself, and come back once you have some code and a specific question. Consider reviewing the helpful article [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: will look into it

Comment: Just do what you're already doing again in the opposite order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some code that outputs your whole thing:

```
asterisks = 7

def output_one(n):
    return ((1+n*2)*'*').center(asterisks)

def output_two(n):
    return "+"

def output_three(n):
    x = abs((n-(asterisks // 2 + 1)))
    return "*" * x + " " * ((asterisks + 2) - 2 * x) + "*" * x


for n in range(asterisks // 2 + 1):
    print(output_one(n), output_two(n), output_three(n))
for n in range(asterisks // 2 - 1, -1, -1):
    print(output_one(n), output_two(n), output_three(n))
```

Output:

```
   *    + **** ****
  ***   + ***   ***
 *****  + **     **
******* + *       *
 *****  + **     **
  ***   + ***   ***
   *    + **** ****
```

It outputs the things in three lines. You can change them to be whatever you want them to be by changing the functions.

Answer (score 1):

You need make range from `(-asterisks // 2+1)+1` to `(asterisks // 2+1)`. Here is an example for figure 1:

```
asterisks = 7

r = asterisks // 2+1
for i in range(-r+1, r): 
    print(((asterisks - abs(i*2))*'*').center(7))
```

Output:

```
   *   
  ***  
 ***** 
*******
 ***** 
  ***  
   *
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you do this?

```
asterisks = 7
for i in range(asterisks // 2+1): 
    print(((1+i*2)*'*').center(asterisks))
asterisks -= 2
for j in range(asterisks // 2+1):
    print("", ((asterisks - (2*j))*'*').center(asterisks))center(asterisks))
```

Answer (score 1):

For the first one:

```
asterisks = 7

r = asterisks // 2+1
for i in range(-r+1, r): 
    print(((asterisks - abs(i*2))*'*').center(7))
```

For the second one:

```
asterisks = 7

r = asterisks // 2+1
space = []
for i in range(-r+1, r): 
    space.extend([asterisks - abs(i*2)])
for j in range(asterisks):
    x = ((asterisks+2) - space[j]) / 2
    print((int(x)*'*') + (int(space[j])*' ') + (int(x)*'*'))
```

Answer (score 1):

it's code golf time \o/

```
steps = 3
for i in range(2*steps+1):
    back = abs(steps-i)
    fore = 2*steps+1-2*back
    print(' '*back+'*'*fore+' '*back+' + '+'*'*(back+1)+' '*fore+'*'*(back+1))
```

`step = 3` gives

```
   *    + **** ****
  ***   + ***   ***
 *****  + **     **
******* + *       *
 *****  + **     **
  ***   + ***   ***
   *    + **** ****
```

and `step = 4`

```
    *     + ***** *****
   ***    + ****   ****
  *****   + ***     ***
 *******  + **       **
********* + *         *
 *******  + **       **
  *****   + ***     ***
   ***    + ****   ****
    *     + ***** *****
```

edited to remove the magic number